# asp.net mvc querystring param

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

i call page like host/home/controller/id. now in view i want to get 'id', i do it like this

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

is any other short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to retrieve it would be in your Model... if present, which I think it alway should...

Comment: but if i need write link <%= Html.ActionLink("Галереи", "GalleryList", "Admin", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }, null)%>

Comment: <%= Html.ActionLink("Галереи", "GalleryList", "Admin", new { id = model.Id }, null)%>